# RGB video ADC for oscilloscope?

Tags: adc, oscilloscope

I was wondering if an ADC like this https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad9883a.pdf would work for making an oscilloscope. Will it work? Is it suitable?

*added*

I found an ADC that says says it works both for imaging and communications. There is a clamp circuit example on page 13 https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad9280.pdf . Maybe the AD9883 works similarly? Seems like clamp may even be a good thing? So the real problems may be the hsync/vsync?

PS: Most likely not going to use either, just trying to understand why it's not suitable.

Comment: no it has clamp input circuit

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist What if the internal clamp is disabled and external clamp pin is never enabled? Is that possible? [clamp function = external signal, clamp polarity = active high, clamp pin grounded]. This should mean that dc offset will never be applied, right? Are there any other issues with this ADC?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist If I understand correctly, the clamp offset can be set at startup with zero input to ADC, and need not be reset again. [for RGB 4:4:4] Is this not so?

Comment: The video is clamped to 0V with an AC coupled input with Hsync

Comment: A single 100 megasample ADC isn't too expensive, sufficient for more tasks than it isn't, and designing and fabricating a decent front end for that will be enough challenge to keep you busy for a while.  You'd probably want to follow with an FPGA or possibly a new-generation USB fifo chip.  You'll also need a trigger.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Maybe a couple of 125MSPS ADC and a CPLD like a EPM7128SLC84 https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/ds/archives/m7000.pdf to make a 25MHz dual channel scope? I don't have much experience, so this may take years. If it does work, I can play with equivalent time sampling etc. I guess a 25MHz+ analog frontend will be really hard work, especially with hardware trigger. Any recommended resources online that go into this in detail, like explaining example front ends etc, and also teardown and design analysis you speak of?

Comment: Once you get beyond a single ADC, you're no longer doing a project for fun and to maybe use a little, but designing a product that only makes sense to build in quantity.  And if you're going to design a product, you need to be able to research current designs yourself at at least the level of a web search, come to understand why a CPLD is insufficient, etc.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I meant 1 ADC per channel (2 ADC for 2 channels). But maybe that is already complicated. Clearly, I have to figure out a lot. [e.g. a 125MHz CPLD will not do equivalent time sampling with 125MSPS data, I guess...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ADC is designed rather specifically for use in a video digitizer application. It is unlikely to work well in other scenarios. (Additionally, Analog has declared the part NRND -- Not Recommended for New Designs -- so it is a poor choice for a new application anyway.)

The biggest problems you're likely to run into have to do with blanking intervals.  It's not clear whether the AD9883A would operate correctly without some sort of regular sync input. More importantly, the ADC is designed to accept capacitively coupled inputs, and self-zeroes during horizontal/vertical blanking intervals. A static or slowly changing input would not be digitized properly.

If you just want a high-speed general-purpose ADC, [Analog has plenty of those](https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/10826). There's no reason to try to shoehorn a video ADC into this application.

Comment: I guess you're right. There may even be timing and coupling assumptions for video, that are not even in the datasheet. 3x 100MSPS channels was enticing though. Those ADC quickly become expensive after 50-100MSPS. I wonder how they make a $400 100MHZ oscilloscope with a $400 ADC.

Comment: @Indraneel - cheap bench scopes (in)famously use multiple ADCs with an analog bandwidth much higher than their sample rate, sampling in turns typically coordinated (and difference compensated) by an FPGA or ASIC.  The manufacturers get good deals on them in quantity; there have been allegations that in some cases they're run in excess of the public data sheet specs, either in a way the scope maker determined on their own could work or with engineering cooperation from the silicon vendor.   You can find teardown design analysis online for many popular scopes.